# PostgreSQL - How to use Crosstab request

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I have a lulc table with a lulc column which looks like that:

`select distinct lulc.lulc from lulc`

| lulc |
| --- |
| Transport - Roads |
| Transport - Other |
| Green space - Forest |
| Urban Fabric - Low - Non Res |
| Urban Fabric - High - NonRes |
| Open space |
| Transport - Rail |
| Urban Fabric - High - Res |
| Urabn Fabric - Low - Res |
| Green space - Other |

I would like to have the percentage of a each land use inside a specific buffer zone.

I have a good result for a single lulc when I do that

```
select 
sensors.sensors_name, 
(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Union(lulc.geom),st_buffer(sensors.geom,200,'quad_segs=50'))) / ST_Area(st_buffer(sensors.geom,200,'quad_segs=50')))*100 as percent_roads_200
    from sensors
            JOIN lulc ON ST_Dwithin (sensors.geom,lulc.geom,200)
                where lulc.lulc like 'Transport - Roads'
                    group by sensors.sensors_name, sensors.geom
```

| sensors_name | percent_roads_200 |
| --- | --- |
| 01965 | 9,58 |
| 01966 | 14,58 |

But I would like to have a result like this with all the lulc

| sensors_name | percent_roads_200 | percent_rail_200 | percent_green_200 | percent_forest_200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01965 | 9,58 | x,xx | x,xx | x,xx |
| 01966 | 14,58 | x,xx | x,xx | x,xx |

I tried to use the `crosstab` request but I didn't manage to get a good result

This is what I tried

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;
    
    select * from crosstab 
('select sensors.sensors_name,  
lulc,
(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Union(lulc.geom),st_buffer(sensors.geom,200,''quad_segs=50''))) / ST_Area(st_buffer(sensors.geom,200,''quad_segs=50'')))*100,
(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Union(lulc.geom),st_buffer(sensors.geom,100,''quad_segs=50''))) / ST_Area(st_buffer(sensors.geom,100,''quad_segs=50'')))*100 
    from sensors JOIN lulc ON ST_Dwithin (sensors.geom,lulc.geom,200) GROUP BY sensors.sensors_name, lulc.lulc, sensors.geom') as test ("lulc" text, "buff_200" real, "buff_100" real);
```

and the message error was this :

**SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: invalid source data SQL statement
Détail : The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.**

As I tried to explain earlier I don't know how to use `crosstab` in my case

Comment: Please edit your question and share your simple data as text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.

Comment: Hello SelVazi, I have deleted the images and I think I have just understood how to use the tables correctly. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Saying you *didn't get a good result* is pretty much useless as we cannot see what you actually did nor the results. Please post the query you tried with `crosstab` and the results or error it produced.

Comment: Hello Belayer, I have add what you asked. I hope it will help you to understand what I would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution to my issue with the request `with CTE`

In the first step, I create temporary table.
In the second step, I do a select with a join between the temporary tables.